# Probability of a graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Given a graph $G=(v, \varepsilon)$, where $v$ is the set of vertices and $\varepsilon$ is the set of edges of the graph, I would like to write the probability $p(G)$ of $G\in\mathcal{G}$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a family of graphs which have 5 possible types of node data $\{A, B, C, D, \text{null}\}$ and 4 possible types of edges $\{I, II, III, \text{null}\}$. Under the assumption of independence, What would be the best way to express $p(G)$?

My attempt: I define $f$ as a vector of dimension $N=|v|$ and $W$ as a matrix of dimension $N\times N$. So far, I can write

$$p(G)=p(f, W)$$

Then, for each element in $f$, I need to define a probability vector of different classes. So I define $\tilde{f}$ as a matrix of size $N\times 5$ and $\tilde{W}$ as a tensor of size $N\times N\times 4$. Any suggestions for best mathematical expression for $p(f, W)$? Would $p(f_{i, 1\leq i\leq N}, W_{i,j, 1\leq i,j\leq N})$ be a valid illustration?

Comment: What kind of thing is $G$ and what does it mean to say $G \in \mathcal{G}$?

Comment: Corrected. Does it make sense now?